# Python: I want the user to see in REALTIME the number of characters he enters in INPUT?

Tags: python-3.x, input

```
answer = input("Describe yourself in a few lines (only 200 characters allowed): ")
```

**for example in this case how i can do?**

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Python3 on Macbook

Comment: I would suggest looking into curses (stdlib) or blessed (3rd-party)

Answer (score 0):

Not using `input`. You need to get the characters the user enters one keystroke at a time:

```
import os, sys, tty, termios


def getchr():
    r"""
    Get a single key from the terminal without printing it.

    Certain special keys return several "characters", all starting with the
    escape character '\x1b'. You could react to that by reading two more
    characters, but the actual escape key will only make this return a single
    escape character, and since it's blocking, that wouldn't be a good solution
    either.
    """
    fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
    old = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
    if ord(ch) == 3:  # ^C
        raise KeyboardInterrupt
    return ch

def input_with_hud(prompt=""):
    buf = []
    while True:
        hud = f"({len(buf)})"
        typed = "".join(buf)
        cols = os.get_terminal_size().columns
        print(
            f"\r{prompt+typed:{cols-len(hud)}s}{hud}",
            end="",
            flush=True,
        )
        char = getchr()
        if char == "\r":  # enter
            print()
            return typed
        elif char == "\x7f":  # backspace
            if buf:
                buf.pop()
        elif char == "\x1b":  # escape
            # note that this won't work with arrow keys
            return None
        else:
            buf.append(char)
```

This has a few downsides, which you will notice when trying it out, notably:

- special keys (e.g. arrow keys) don't work
- at least on my terminal the cursor is missing
- it doesn't work on Windows

You can fix all of that, but it's a bit of work, so the easiest solution is probably indeed curses or something like that.

Comment: Its look pretty difficult, I'll try with curses, thanks!!